# How should I store weather station data?

Tags: mysql, database

I have been storing weather station data in my MySQL database. All the weather stations have different sensors, and I have a column for each (totaling 100+).

The data table is structured as such - id,StationID,date,sensor1,sensor2,sensor3..sensor100.

Each sensor column is a null if there isn't data.

Example:

[image]

Normalized structure - id,StationID,date,sensor,value

Example:

[image]

The issue I have with the normalized structure is that the datetime is duplicated for each row. Wouldn't the normalized structure take up more space? What's the best approach to storing this type of data?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying all the weather stations report data for the same date-time moment, at the same intervals? And: Do all the sensors of each station report at the same time every time?

Comment: If `BLID` is the station id, what is the `id` column, the first column?

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for the response. No they will have different datetimes and can range from 15 minute intervals to hourly. The id is the primary key.

Comment: When you say "they" do you mean the stations as a whole, or each instrument reports at various times. You have to be *extremely* precise and detailed here to determine a proper structure. As currently written, your question lacks the necessary detail.

Comment: The example data on your first screenshot shows exactly quarter-hour sampling. Is that not typical data? If not, show sample of realistic data inputs.

Comment: Each station as a whole. The example data in the first screenshot is typical data

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the repeating dates. Yes, you could have a separate table that stores reporting events (id, station_id, datetime), and then store the sensor details associated with that event id in another table, but it's not going to gain you much.

Comment: Also, in the normalised schema, I wouldn't bother storing the null sensors

Comment: And remember space is cheap. Time is expensive.

Comment: @Strawberry Great , thanks. I thought normalizing was the way to go. Would the normalized structure make querying faster through removing nulls and reducing columns? I'm going to run some tests today.

Comment: The tests will tell you more than I ever could. But remember that indexes are crucial!

Comment: @Strawberry Sure! Thank you.